# How do I stub out current_user inside of view spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I want to make sure this link is displayed only when both user values are set:

```
- if current_user.dms.present? and current_user.dms_id.present?
  = link_to "Import Items", "#"
```

How do I stub out that `current_user` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure you add the helpers for both views and controllers?

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :view
end
```

Comment: nice. I was missing the `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :view` line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Devise Gem for your current_user, have you tried using the Devise Test Helpers (Devise::TestHelpers)? They allow you to sign and in and sign out a user, and therefore access the current_user record in your controller and view specs.

The Devise Wiki has a page on this:
[Devise Wiki for TestHelpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

Comment: I see that all examples are for controller. Will they work in the view spec too?

Comment: So far I'm getting errors: `undefined method sign_in`. However in controller tests `sign_in` works.